# how to delegate evaluation of multiple columns to database server in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a sql table and let's say I have some columns and 6 of them are boolean fields indicating related information. For example isMercedes, isBMW, isHonda, etc. I know this violates a lot of database design principles, but that's what I got given. When I display the results on a grid, I need to show car name. If isMercedes is true, then I should display "Mercedes". Only one of the boolean fields can be true. How can I delegate this conversion to database server using linq to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

For example in linq to sql query

```
CarModel = record.isMercedes == true ? "Mercedes" : (record.isBMW == true ? "BMW" : (record.isHonda == true ? "Honda" : ""))
```

The above snippet from linq query is turned into sql.

```
(CASE
     WHEN [t1].[isMercedes] = 1 THEN @p0
     WHEN [t1].[isBMW] = 1 THEN CONVERT(NVarChar(12),@p1)
```